# Extract internal variable from anonymous function

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous-function

as the title says I want to extract the variable **status** to be able to use it in another part of the code, is this possible?

```
RNAudioStreamer.status((err, status)=>{if(!err) console.log(status)})
```

Comment: No. Put the other part of the code inside the callback (or call it from there, at least).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the callback sync/async you can create a global variable or use promise.

```
let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  RNAudioStreamer.status((err, status)=>{
    if(!err) resolve(status); else reject(err); 
  })      
});

// ...


p.then(status => {
  // process status here
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I want to make a global variable how could it be done?

Comment: Simply make an assignment in your callback to a variable described out of the callback